# Cannot access Host Docker Engine inside Container

Tags: windows, docker

**Short Version:** How do I access the docker host from within a (windows server core) container on Windows?

**Long Version:** I’ve created an image based on microsoft/dotnet-framework-build:3.5 to install tools used during our CI/CD process.

During the build I install chocolatey and then, using choco, installer the docker CLI client. This is so I can push images, stored on the host, from within the container running (the build image), at least that was my hope.

The problem I have is that I cannot seem to bind the host `\\.\pipe\docker_engine` to the pipe in the container. So far I’ve tried the following command line options (these start an interactive prompt for testing but the proper build will be non-interactive)

```
docker run --interactive --tty -v \\.\pipe\docker_engine:\\.\pipe\docker_engine my-image
```

In this case the container starts but the binding doesn’t work because when I run docker ps I get the error:

`error during connect: Get http://%2F%2F.%2Fpipe%2Fdocker_engine/v1.33/version: open //./pipe/docker_engine: message readmode pipes not supported In the default daemon configuration on Windows, the docker client must be run elevated to connect. This error may also indicate that the docker daemon is not running.`

```
docker run --interactive --tty `
           --mount type=bind,src=\\.\pipe\docker_engine,dst=\\.\pipe\docker_engine `
           my-image
```

In this case the container won’t even start because I get the error:

`Error response from daemon: invalid mount config for type "bind": source path must be a directory`

How do I bind the .\pipe\docker_engine so that the container can access the docker engine on the host?

The version info from my host install is:

```
Client:
 Version:       17.12.0-ce
 API version:   1.35
 Go version:    go1.9.2
 Git commit:    c97c6d6
 Built: Wed Dec 27 20:05:22 2017
 OS/Arch:       windows/amd64

Server:
 Engine:
  Version:      17.12.0-ce
  API version:  1.35 (minimum version 1.24)
  Go version:   go1.9.2
  Git commit:   c97c6d6
  Built:        Wed Dec 27 20:15:52 2017
  OS/Arch:      windows/amd64
  Experimental: true
```

The client, inside the container, version info is

```
Client:
 Version:      17.10.0-ce
 API version:  1.33
 Go version:   go1.8.3
 Git commit:   f4ffd25
 Built:        Tue Oct 17 19:00:02 2017
 OS/Arch:      windows/amd64
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just to round this off…

The only way I could get this working was to add another host to daemon.json, the host is on the docker nat network. So tcp://nat_network_address:2375

I then set a firewall rule to allow the traffic and within the container set the DOCKER_HOST environment variable to the new endpoint.

After that I was able to connect to the host’s docker engine.

It’s not ideal but it works until a proper fix is available.

Kepboy

**Update:** This has been fixed.  You can now mount the host named pipe inside the container.

`docker run --interactive --tty -v \\.\pipe\docker_engine:\\.\pipe\docker_engine my-image`

Comment: Once the issue is resolved the correct way to communicate with the docker engine on the host would be (I assume) to map the named pipe into the container